# phpMyAdmin -how to manually change datetime value

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

phpMyAdmin - I need to manually change datetime value in a column.

current value - `2018-11-03 20:47:18`

desired value - `2018-11-02 20:41:50`

After editing the cell and pressing `Enter` the result is:

`2018-11-02 20:41:50.000000`

I tried multiple times - seems there is no way - the nulls are always added.

The column is datetime type, without default values.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The zeros at the end are added automatically and make no difference. PHP for example inserts DATETIME without them, but the phpmyadmin editor does. They wont affect the value itself.

If you don't wat to see the zeros, execute the following query:

UPDATE table SET column = "2018-08-20 00:00:00" WHERE id = 999

Comment: so what are the nulls. what is the reason?

Comment: I think they are for display milliseconds, so .000000 just means "and 0 milliseconds"

Comment: the way how the pma editor is implemented always adds the milliseconds, even if it's 0. But like I said, I doesn't make any difference.

Comment: `00` could be `0` milliseconds and not `000000`

Comment: The documentation of the fractional seconds is here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html

MYSQL just decided to use 6 digit precision